# All user created stored procedures not showing in object explorer

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

When connected to all databases in one of our Production environments in SQL Server Management Studio v18.11.1, under "Programmability - Stored Procedures", only system stored procedures appear, no user built stored procedures are shown. In a second production environment, I believe the database user has the same permissions as the first, but the problem isn't happening there.

After I run the following code :

```
SELECT
    [UserName] = CASE princ.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN princ.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                 END,
    [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],
    [Role] = null,
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM
    --database user
    sys.database_principals princ
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE
    princ.[type] in ('S','U')
UNION
--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
SELECT
    [UserName] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN memberprinc.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                 END,
    [DatabaseUserName] = memberprinc.[name],
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM
    --Role/member associations
    sys.database_role_members members
JOIN
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
JOIN
    --Role members (database users)
    sys.database_principals memberprinc ON memberprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on memberprinc.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
UNION
--List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
SELECT
    [UserName] = '{All Users}',
    [UserType] = '{All Users}',
    [DatabaseUserName] = '{All Users}',
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc
LEFT JOIN
    --Role permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
JOIN
    --All objects
    sys.objects obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE
    --Only roles
    roleprinc.[type] = 'R' AND
    --Only public role
    roleprinc.[name] = 'public' AND
    --Only objects of ours, not the MS objects
    obj.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY
    princ.[Name],
    OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    col.[name],
    perm.[permission_name],
    perm.[state_desc],
    obj.type_desc--perm.[class_desc]
```

It shows the same following permissions for both users on both environments:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the procedures are in the `dbo` schema in both environments? Does the user have a different default schema in one of the environments?

Comment: Both environments are (effectively) replicas, same schema, same SP's. Just for different countries that my company operates in

Comment: My entry point into diagnosing permissions issues is looking at sys.login_token (to get any server-level roles), sys.user_token (to get any database-level roles) and sys.database_permissions. The first two I run while impersonating the login under consideration - no predicates necessary. The last I run with a simple `where grantee_principal_id = user_id()` (also while under impersonation).

Answer (score 0):

The "View definition" permission being denied may cause the problem.
[image: definition]

Comment: Both users have public roles and both users have the same EXECUTE permissions on SP's which should give View Definition permissions by default. I can see that both users have the exact same permissions, the difference being the one that works uses database user to access, and the one that doesn't work uses windows authentication